# Count rows in each 'partition' of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Disclaimer: I don't mean *partition* in the [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) sense, nor [table partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html); I mean it in the [more general sense](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/partition), i.e. to divide up.

Here's a table:

```
id  |  y
----+------------
1   |  1
2   |  1
3   |  1
4   |  2
5   |  2
6   |  null
7   |  2
8   |  2
9   |  null
10  |  null
```

I'd like to partition by checking equality on `y`, such that I end up with counts of the number of times each value of `y` appears contiguously, when sorted on `id` (i.e. in the order shown).

Here's the output I'm looking for:

```
y    | count
-----+----------
1    | 3
2    | 2
null | 1
2    | 2
null | 2
```

So reading down the rows in that output we have:

- The first partition of three `1`'s
- The first partition of two `2`'s
- The first partition of a `null`
- The second partition of two `2`'s
- The second partition of two `null`s

Comment: In other words, you want to count *contiguous series* in a table, or partition by the "edge" where a series of values changes to a different value. You'll find a variety of existing solutions to that problem here, most using the `lag` window function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT y, count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT y,
         sum( xyz ) OVER ( 
           ORDER BY id 
           rows between unbounded preceding
            and current row
         ) qwe
  FROM (
     SELECT *,
            case 
            when y is null and
                 lag(y) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) is null
                 then 0
            when y = lag(y) OVER ( ORDER BY id )
            then 0 
            else 1 end xyz
     FROM table1
  ) alias
) alias
GROUP BY qwe, y
ORDER BY qwe;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b1794/12